# Testing a Container.DataItem with inline code

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0, repeater

I would like to do something like this in ASP.Net 2.0:

```
 <asp:Repeater id="myRepeater" runat="server">
      <ItemTemplate>
           <% if (DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MyProperty").Equals("SomeValue")) { %>
                <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MyProperty")%>
           <% } %>
      </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

But I cannot test the DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MyProperty") like this.

NOTE: I don't have access to the source code, I can only change the aspx inline.

NOTE2: I know I can use this:

```
 <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MyProperty").Equals("SomeValue")?"<!--":""%>
```

but I was looking for a cleaner way.

Is there a way to test the Container.DataItem with inline code inside a Repeater?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do this. You bind your "visibility" function to the visible property of an asp:literal control:

```
<asp:Repeater id="myRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:literal runat='server' id='mycontrol' 
          visible='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MyProperty").Equals("SomeValue") %>'>
          <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MyProperty") %>
        </asp:literal>
     </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could refactor it out to server side script.

```
<script runat="server">
protected string ShowIfEqual(RepeaterItem Item, string SomeValue) {
   YourTypeThatIsDataBound _item = (YourTypeThatIsDataBound)Item.DataItem;
   return _item.MyProperty == SomeValue ? _item.MyProperty : string.Empty;
}
</script>
```

And the call it inline as...

```
<%#ShowIfEqual(Container, "SomeValue")%>
```

Comment: it is not inline

Answer (score 1):

What about the "else-case"?

It looks ugly, not really readable!

```
<asp:Repeater id="myRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%--(if true part)--%>
        <asp:literal runat='server'
          visible='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"OrderCount") > 0%>'> 
            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "OrderCount") %>
        </asp:literal>
        <%--(else part)--%>
        <asp:literal runat='server'
          visible='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"OrderCount") ==0%>'>
            <p>yet no orders</p>
        </asp:literal>
     </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score -4):

No, there's no other way to do this.